# Modifying ATriggerSphere radius?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I've created an instance of ATriggerSphere in my game, and placed it at my character's location, like so:

```
//Create activate trigger radius
activateRadiusTrigger = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<ATriggerSphere>(ATriggerSphere::StaticClass(),GetActorLocation(), GetActorRotation());
activateRadiusTrigger->SetActorHiddenInGame(false);
```

I need to adjust its radius now. I see that in blueprints there's a parameter under Shape that lets me change the value of "Sphere Radius", but I can't find the C++ equivalent field. Can someone tell me how that's done? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up TriggerSphere.h in the engine headers, you can find its public interface there. It looks like ATriggerSphere uses a collision component that you can get using GetCollisionComponent(). I'm going to assume this component is a USphereComponent, and you can call SetSphereRadius on that!

so try:

```
Cast<USphereComponent>(activateRadiusTrigger->GetCollisionComponent())->SetSphereRadius(NewRadius);
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to find that eventually, but I thought I'd let someone grab up the answer.